# Varrer codigo-fonte e encontrar url do wikipedia

Tags: php

Estou com problema no regex :/

Estava a usar essa pattern para obter urls do wikipedia apartir do codigo fonte das buscas do google `wikipedia\.org[^\" ]+`

Porem as urls estao encrostadas dessa forma: `<a href="/url?q=http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_World_Tour&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=yS6WVOvAA9HLsAShkYGoCw&amp;ved=0CBQQFjAB&amp;usg=AFQjCNFbV5WzVcG-aJbrvGdhbxz3wnPUKg" s` ele acaba me resultando: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_World_Tour&sa=U&ei=yS6WVOvAA9HLsAShkYGoCw&ved=0CBQQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNFbV5WzVcG-aJbrvGdhbxz3wnPUKg

Porem isso nao é url valida do wikipedia o correto seria apenas `http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_World_Tour`

Answer (score 5):

Dado o URL não conter o caractere `?` que é a denotação do início da *query string*, uma maneira simples é fazendo uso de uma expressão regular que vai remover tudo após o primeiro `&`:

```
$url = 'http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_World_Tour&sa=U&ei=yS6WVOvAA9HLsAShkYGoCw&ved=0CBQQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNFbV5WzVcG-aJbrvGdhbxz3wnPUKg';

$url = preg_replace('/\&.*/', '', $url);
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/v2aqiy):

```
echo $url; // Saída: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_World_Tour
```

Comment: Hey, qual regex eu poderia utilizar para encontrar uma url da wikipedia? estava tentando com um desse `(.*).wikipedia.org\/wiki\/(.*)[ ]+`

Comment: @user3163662 Isso vai depender do que estás a fazer, uma RegEx pode nem ser a forma ideal. Abre uma pergunta com um exemplo do código e assim será fácil ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo visto você quer pegar o link do Wikipedia através de uma busca no Google correto?

Bem, acabei de criar e testar uma solução para você, talvez não uma das melhores, entretanto funciona! :D

```
<?

    $TermoDeBusca = urlencode('ASP World Tour'); // Termo de Busca

    // Curl! 
    $ch = curl_init ("");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com.br/search?q='.$TermoDeBusca);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'); 
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    // DOM!
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
    $items = $xpath->query("//h3[contains(@class, 'r')]//a"); //Pega dentro do <H3> (de classe 'r') o valor do <a>



        foreach ($items as $pega){ // Loop, para cada link

            $link = $pega->getAttribute('href'); // Será: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP_World_Tour

                if (strpos($link,'wikipedia.org') == true) { // Verifica se o $link contem o 'wikipedia.org', ou seja, se é do wikipedia ~~ gambiarra
                echo $link.'<br>'; // se for, ele mostra o link
                } // fimse

        } //fim do foreach
?>
```

Tentei comentar o máximo que pude, infelizmente não tenho tempo para isso.
Fiz o que pude! :D